# Amount of users in a group where one particular user is present mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize this query but I can't seem to get it. Any help is more than welcomed. This is inside a stored procedure, so the 1 is replaced by an IN parameter.

---

Table **userGroupRelation**

userGroupID BIGINT --> foreign key to userGroupID in groups table

userID BIGINT --> foreign key to the users table

---

Table **folders**

ownerID BIGINT --> foreign key to the users table

postersGroup BIGINT --> foreign key to userGroupID in groups table

other stuff ...

---

```
SELECT folders.*,COUNT(userGroupRelation.userID) AS users
  FROM folders
LEFT JOIN userGroupRelation
  ON folders.postingGroupID = userGroupRelation.userGroupID
WHERE folders.ownerID = 1
  OR userGroupRelation.userGroupID IN (
    SELECT userGroupID FROM userGroupRelation WHERE userID = 1)
GROUP BY folders.folderID;
```

---

I basically want to get all the folders a user can see (either because he owns it or because he is in a group of posters for that folder)

Comment: can you post table structures on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two approaches. One is similar to your own, but removing the subquery and correcting the `COUNT` clause. I should mention it is unclear from your question whether the `COUNT ... AS users` result is of importance here, since you only specified you want to get all folders for a user.

```
SELECT 
  folders.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(userGroupRelation.userID, folders.ownerID)) AS users
FROM 
  folders
  LEFT JOIN userGroupRelation ON folders.postingGroupID = userGroupRelation.userGroupID
WHERE 
  folders.ownerID = 1
  OR userGroupRelation.userID = 1
GROUP BY 
  folders.folderID
;
```

This is somewhat better than your own solution because the subquery is eliminated, but it still leaves with this `OR` condition which is difficult to optimize -- it works on two different tables.

**Edit**: this next solution neither answers the question nor does it work at all :(

A completely different approach is to start with the `users` table (assuming you have one, of course):

```
SELECT 
  folders.*
FROM 
  users
  LEFT JOIN folders ON (folders.ownerID = users.id)
  LEFT JOIN userGroupRelation ON (userGroupRelation.userId = users.id)
  LEFT JOIN folders ON (folders.postingGroupID = userGroupRelation.userGroupID)
WHERE 
  users.id = 1
GROUP BY 
  folders.folderID
;
```

This one is far better optimized if you have proper indexes on `users.id` and all joining columns. However:

1. It will not tell you the amount of (other) users per folder
2. `SELECT filders.* .... GROUP BY filders.folderId` is not strictly valid SQL -- though it will work if you're not using strict `sql_mode`. From you own query I can see you're not, so I won't dwell into that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm sorry I didn't clarify, but I do need to know if I have other posters in the folders, and that is why I added the IN (because if not, the owner of the folder would not see the real amount of other posters for it.

Comment: I see, Then please ignore second offered solution. You are also right about the "not a unique table/alias" -- I did not have schema/data to work on -- therefore could not verify the query. Not only is there an ambiguity -- it could also not be easily solved. The second offered solution is simply incorrect.